# Apart from looking nice, what isthe point of TFS2012 State Diagrams

Tags: sharepoint

I have found the state diagram feature of work items (see link below).

It looks nice, but what does it do? Is it functional, or does it just show the outcomes of various choices e.g. when choosing "resolved" it will do the resolved line?

[Hidden Gems - State Diagrams](http://roadtoalm.com/2011/10/03/hidden-gems-in-tfspart-2-work-item-state-diagrams/)

Comment: The state diagram helps to understand the possible workflow of your Work Item Type. For example in the company I work currently for we have a Work Item Type with 18 different states. This diagram helped a lot for the development and later for explaining how it works.

Answer (score 0):

That feature was available in TFS 2010 but was removed in TFS 2012.  It was only to show the workflow of that item type and how it transitioned based on its state. So you could not click the images and have it update the item.

Comment: It is still available in the TFS Web Dashboard in TFS2012

Comment: @Dom where is that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is still available in TFS 2012. What you need is Sharepoint installed with your TFS installation.
When you open your SharePoint-TeamProject side and create a new work item it will show you the button to display the state diagram.

Also have a look here:
http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/Where-are-Work-Item-State-Diagrams-in-TFS-2012.aspx